# Controling Option Menu availability

Tags: android, android-intent, android-menu

I have an activity (act2), which can be launched from act1 or act3. If it is launched from act1, I would like for my option menu to be available, meaning when you press the menu button, it shows up. If it is launched from act3, I have nothing that needs to be in the option menu so I would like for it not to appear when you press menu. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are invoking act2 from act1 pass a boolean variable as `true` through bundle. And if you are invoking act2 from act3 pass it as `false` or don't pass it at all.

In your act2 and specially in `onCreate()` method catch that boolean variable. You have to be careful that if you are not passing a bundle from act3 it will throw `null pointer exception` in act2 while doing this operation. Now you can get a boolean variable that helps act2 to determine where it came from. [if its true than it came from act1 or from act2].

now override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in your activity, it returns boolean. So if you pass `true` than the menu items will pop up when you press menu button, or no menu items will pop up if you return `false`. Use that boolean variable you fetched from onCreate() method, you can simply return it so when its `true`[from act1] menu will be shown or in case of `false`[from act3] it will not be shown at all.

Answer (score 2):

Using Intents, it is possible. For example:

In act1, while launching act2,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Act2.class);
    intent.putExtra("showmenu", true);
    startActivity(intent);
```

In act3, you can either set it to false, or do nothing.

In act2, check and show

```
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra("showmenu", false))
        //show option menu
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is launched from act1:

```
Intent io = new Intent(act1.this, act2.class);
    io.putExtra("enableOptionMenu", 1);
    startActivity(io);
```

If it is launched from act3:

```
Intent io = new Intent(act3.this, act2.class);
    io.putExtra("enableOptionMenu", 0);
    startActivity(io);
```

In act2 you read "enableOptionMenu" in onCreate:

```
int enableOptionMenu;
    Intent i = getIntent();
    enableOptionMenu = i.getIntExtra("enableOptionMenu", 0);
```

and finally check that enableOptionMenu in onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (enableOptionMenu == 1) {    
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_act2, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```